# Как сделать переключение языка в программе?

Tags: android, android-studio, локализация

Для локализации приложения создал два ресурсных файла `strings.xml` с помощью Android Studio. Когда в настройках телефона меняю язык, то интерфейс программы меняется как и положено.

Как при помощи нажатия кнопки можно переключать язык интерфейса в самой программе? Желательно без перезагрузки приложения или хотя бы сделать это автоматически.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вбиваем в гугл

> [android change locale programmatically](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20change%20locale%20programmatically)

2. Идём по первой ссылке: [Change language programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2900023/3212712)
3. Узнаём там, что это не рекомендуется делать (сменять язык не через настройки телефона) и, если всё же хотим, то копипастим код:

   ```
   Resources res = context.getResources();
   // Change locale settings in the app.
   DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
   android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
   conf.locale = new Locale(language_code.toLowerCase());
   res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
   ```

Надо заметить, что после назначения языка может понадобиться пересоздать активити так (в классе активити): `recreate()`

Comment: @АлександрТымчук, ну да, через SharedPrefs можно сохранить, а потом в самом начале onCreate метода активити применить код из вопроса.

Comment: updateConfiguration устарело и не работает на Андроид 9, Андроид 10

Comment: @user_MGU, видимо теперь надо что-то типа такого вызывать: `Context.createConfigurationContext(Configuration)`

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо подменять контекст, в который установлена другая локаль. Вот [статья по теме](https://habr.com/ru/company/redmadrobot/blog/461085/).

```
override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
    super.attachBaseContext(applySelectedAppLanguage(base))
}

private fun applySelectedAppLanguage(context: Context): Context {
    val locale = settingsInteractor.getUserSelectedLanguageBlocking()
    val newConfig = Configuration(context.resources.configuration)
    Locale.setDefault(locale)
    newConfig.setLocale(locale)
    return context.createConfigurationContext(newConfig)
}
```