# Выбор языка с главного экрана

Tags: android

Хочу на первом экране android приложения сделать выбор из 3 языков, соответственно 3 кнопки. Подскажите, как реализовать, если можно, для "чайников".

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать переключение языка в программе?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/544944/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b5)

Comment: И плюс [ещё множество вариантов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: Локализация приложений на Андроиде делается в ресурсах и выбирается автоматически по настройкам аппарата, но если Вам всё же хочется дать юзеру ручной выбор: http://snowpard-android-ru.blogspot.ru/2013/03/android.html?m=1 - ровно то что Вы хотите.